# import hadoop src as Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I want to import Hadoop source 2.7 to Eclipse as a Maven project, but get these errors:

[image]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change default Eclipse Maven to your own Maven installation folder.

You can find this option here:

```
Window - Preferences - Maven - Installation
```

Just add new Maven home dir and mark it as default.

If you don't have installed Maven you can use following links:

- [Download Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
- [Install Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)